# Laravel 4.2 + MySQL Running phpunit on Codeship says '.. access denied for user root@localhost ..'

Tags: laravel-4, codeship

I have a Laravel 4.2 with MySQL web application integrated on bitbucket and decided to use Codeship for continuous integration.

When build executes on Codeship it says, '.. access denied for user root@localhost ..'

Here's my Codeship commands:

```
# Set php version through phpenv. 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 available
phpenv local 5.4
# Install extensions through Pecl
# yes yes | pecl install memcache
# Install dependencies through Composer
composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction
```

Here's the Codeship test command:

```
phpunit
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: 
**Setup Commands**

```
# Set php version through phpenv. 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 available
phpenv local 5.4
# Install extensions through Pecl
# yes yes | pecl install memcache
# Install dependencies through Composer
composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed
```

**Test Command(s)**

```
phpunit
```

**Environment Variables**

```
APP_ENV = codeship 
APP_HOST = localhost 
APP_DB = test
```